# Handling dynamically changing column positions and splitting file

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have a unique problem. I have a file with following columns

```
PersonId, AB1, AB2, AB3, DG1_B1,DG1_B2,DG2
1,0,1,0,3,5,7
2,0,3,1,3,7,4
```

I want to split this and create multiple files based on the column prefix. I want the output to be as follows

- `File_AB1.csv`

  ```
  PersonId, AB1, AB2, AB3
  1,0,1,0
  2,0,3,1
  ```
- `File_DG1.csv`

  ```
  PersonId, DG1_B1,DG1_B2
  1,3,5
  2,3,7
  ```
- `File_DG2.csv`

  ```
  PersonId, DG2
  1,7
  2,4
  ```

There is another problem with this file as well. The ordering of the columns can change the next time I get the input file as shown below (note column AB3 moved to the end of the line).

```
PersonId, AB1, AB2,DG1_B1,DG1_B2,DG2,AB3
1,0,1,3,5,7,0
2,0,3,3,7,4,1
```

How can I accomplish this in awk?

Comment: Is it always one file for `AB*` columns, another one for `DG1*` and another for `DG2*`?

Comment: Yeah fedorqui. It will be always one file for AB*, another for DG1* and one for DG2*

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
awk -F, '
  NR == 1 {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
      if (match($i, /AB|DG./))
        file_list[file[i] = "file_" substr($i, RSTART, RLENGTH) ".csv"]
  }
  {
    for (f in file_list) printf "%s", $1 > f
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) printf ",%s", $i > file[i]
    for (f in file_list) print "" > f
  }'
```

(it calls the file `file_AB.csv` (based on the prefix), not `file_AB1.csv`)

Comment: Excellent! What is the need of `l[f[i] = "file" ...` instead of just `l["file" ...]`?

Comment: @fedorqui. It sets the file for the `i`th field (`f[i] = ...`) and also adds that file to the list of files (`l[the-file]`).